# Layoutparams unresolved for cardview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview

Check this android studio error

[image]

I tried same in `java`, it worked and also working fine for `LinerLayout`. Does anyone know what is the issue ?

Comment: Try this `val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )`

Comment: I think layout params should be of the parent item, and my my parent item here is Cardview, if I set any other params, it will give error

Comment: Check this: http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/cardview-in-kotlin-programmatically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on Nilesh Rathod answer, it worked, Thanks

```
val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

```
cardView.setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20));
```